# javascript window interval is not changing

Tags: javascript, gridview, setinterval

I have two updated panels on my web page to display some data and i am refreshing panels after a specific time like this

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
        window.setInterval(function () {
            __doPostBack('<%= UpdatePanel1.ClientID %>', '');
            __doPostBack('<%= UpdatePanel3.ClientID %>', '');
        }, 2000);
    </script>
```

this refreshed the panel each two seconds.Problem is that i have another function for a child grid inside a gridview to open and close with plus and minus images like this

```
function divexpandcollapse(divname) {
        var div = document.getElementById(divname);
        var img = document.getElementById('img' + divname);
        if (div.style.display == "none") {
            div.style.display = "inline";
            img.src = "../Images/Minus.gif";
            window.setInterval(function () {
                __doPostBack('<%= UpdatePanel1.ClientID %>', '');
                __doPostBack('<%= UpdatePanel3.ClientID %>', '');
            }, 20000);
        } else {
            div.style.display = "none";
            img.src = "../Images/Plus.gif";
            window.setInterval(function () {
                __doPostBack('<%= UpdatePanel1.ClientID %>', '');
                __doPostBack('<%= UpdatePanel3.ClientID %>', '');
            }, 2000);

        }
    }
```

I am trying to increase the postback timing from 2 second to 20 when user clikc on plus sign inside gridivew and when again click on minus sign then timing should again 2 second.But through below code its not changing the time accordingly.can any one tell me what exactly i am missing inside this method or what should i have to do extra to get my requirements.plz help

Comment: so what should i do for my requirement

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you do not clear any intervals that may already be attached. You need to keep track of the intervals and if there is one, remove it.

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">

    var timer = window.setInterval(function () {
        __doPostBack('<%= UpdatePanel1.ClientID %>', '');
        __doPostBack('<%= UpdatePanel3.ClientID %>', '');
    }, 2000);
</script>
```

and

```
function divexpandcollapse(divname) {
    var div = document.getElementById(divname);
    var img = document.getElementById('img' + divname);
    if (window.timer) {
        window.clearInterval(timer);
    }
    if (div.style.display == "none") {
        div.style.display = "inline";
        img.src = "../Images/Minus.gif";
        timer = window.setInterval(function () {
            __doPostBack('<%= UpdatePanel1.ClientID %>', '');
            __doPostBack('<%= UpdatePanel3.ClientID %>', '');
        }, 20000);
    } else {
        div.style.display = "none";
        img.src = "../Images/Plus.gif";
        timer = window.setInterval(function () {
            __doPostBack('<%= UpdatePanel1.ClientID %>', '');
            __doPostBack('<%= UpdatePanel3.ClientID %>', '');
        }, 2000);

    }
}
```

Comment: i have to click the plus sign two times then it works properly accordiing to the code,what may b the issue

Comment: Is the display actually none? `console.log(div.style.display); if (div.style.display == "none") {`

Comment: Does it go into the if statement? Does `console.log(div.style.display=="none");` return true?